# Interesting deceiving limit $\lim \int_{0}^{1} (n + 1)x^n f(x) dx$

Tags: limits

I am told that $ \int_{0}^{1} (n + 1)x^n  dx = 1$ and $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. I must find

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} (n + 1)x^n f(x) dx$$

My first impression is that the limit can vary. If $f = 1$, then the limit is just $1$ and if $f = 0$, then the limit is $0$. I was able to bound the whole thing by $\| f \|_\infty$, and so I believe that should be the limit. I have trouble bounding the lower part.

A hint was said to split up the region of $[0,1]$, but i didn't find that useful.

Comment: Do you know the Weierstrass approximation theorem?

Comment: Never mind: from the answers below, we don't need such a big gun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you were asking about Weierstrass Approximation Theorem recently, here's an argument.

Assume first that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable (in particular, a polynomial would satisfy this).  Then, integrating by parts,
\begin{align}
\int_0^1(n+1)x^nf(x)\,dx&=\left.\phantom{\int\!\!\!\!}x^{n+1}f(x)\right|_0^1-\int_0^1x^{n+1}f'(x)\,dx\\ \ \\
&=\left.\phantom{\int\!\!\!\!}x^{n+1}f(x)\right|_0^1-\left.\phantom{\int\!\!\!\!}\frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}f'(x)\right|_0^1+\int_0^1\frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}\,f''(x)\,dx\\ \ \\
&=f(1)-\frac{f'(1)}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+2}\int_0^1 x^{n+2} \,f''(x)\,dx.
\end{align}
It is easy to see that the last integral is bounded by $\|f''\|_\infty$ (which is finite since we assume $f''$ continuous). So, in the limit, 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1(n+1)x^nf(x)\,dx=f(1).
$$

Now, for arbitrary $f$, let $p_n$ be  polynomials with $|f-p_n|<1/n$. Then
$$
\left|\int_0^1(n+1)x^nf(x)\,dx-p_n(1)\right|=\left|\int_0^1(n+1)x^nf(x)\,dx-\int_0^1(n+1)x^np_n(x)\,dx\right|\\
=\left|\int_0^1(n+1)x^n[f(x)-p_n(x)]\,dx\right|\leq\int_0^1(n+1)x^n|f(x)-p_n(x)|\,dx\\
\leq\frac1n\,\int_0^1(n+1)x^n\,dx=\frac1n.
$$
As $p_n(1)\to f(1)$, the above shows that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1(n+1)x^n\,f(x)\,dx=f(1).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Think of $(n+1)x^n$ as a probability density on $[0,1]$.  The integral is the average value of $f$ according to that probability density.  As $n\to\infty$, the density becomes concentrated near $1$, so we expect that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 (n+1)x^n f(x) \,dx = f(1) $$
The idea of splitting up $[0,1]$ is relevant because it allows us to do separate estimates on the part where the density is thin and the part where the density is thick.  Something like this:
$$ \left|\int_0^{1-\delta} (n+1)x^n f(x) \,dx\right|
\le \|f\|_\infty \int_0^{1-\delta} (n+1)x^n \,dx
\to 0 \qquad\text{as $n\to\infty$,} $$
and
$$ \int_{1-\delta}^1 (n+1) x^n f(x) \,dx
\approx f(1) \int_{1-\delta}^1 (n+1) x^n \,dx \to f(1)
$$
So choose $\delta$ so that $|f(1)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ when $1-\delta<x<1$, and try to prove the above.

Comment: How is $\int_{1-\delta}^1 (n+1) x^n f(x) \,dx
\approx f(1) \int_\delta^1 (n+1) x^n \,dx$ justified…?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to fix the $\delta$ in the second integral.  I'll edit it.

Comment: You'll prove it by using that $f(x)\approx f(1)$ on $[1-\delta,1]$.  In general, if $m\le h(x)\le M$ on $[a,b]$ then $m(b-a)\le\int_a^b h(x)\le M(b-a)$.

Comment: Sorry i think I got lost in one part. You have shown that your whole integral is $|.| \leq f(1) \int$, how does that show the limit is $f(1)$? That part remains a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Show that for any continuous function $g:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$, if $g(1) = 0$, then 
$$
\int_0^1(n+1)x^ng(x)\,dx = 0
$$
from there, it suffices to set $g(x) = f(x) - f(1).$

---

A nice way to intuit this limit is to note that for each $n$, we're taking a sort of "average".  Namely, we're finding
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\int_0^1 x^nf(x)\,dx}{\int_0^1 x^n\,dx}
$$

Comment: Can I ask why are we looking at $x = 1$?

Comment: Sure.  Consider the function given by $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n$.  Perhaps that will clarify things.

Comment: The limit is $0$ unless $x = 1$.

Comment: Do you see why this is significant?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why $g(1) = 0$ was important?

Comment: We could talk about any $f$ directly, but $0$ tends to be a lot easier to work with.  Saying $g(1) = 0$ gives you a limit that approaches zero.  Or, are you asking in another way why the value at $x = 1$ is generally important here?

Comment: Why $x = 1$ is important here.

Comment: The answer is because $(n+1)x^n \to 0$ uniformly on every interval of the form $[0,1 - \epsilon]$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.  It follows that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{1 - \epsilon} (n+1)x^n f(x)\,dx = 0
$$
no matter what $f$ happens to be.  So, $x = 1$ matters because everything else doesn't.

Comment: Well I know that, but I don't understand why on $[1 - \epsilon, 1]$, that the thing tends to $f(1).$

Comment: @jip that's up to you to figure out.  Again, I suggest starting with a continuous $g(x)$ satisfying $g(1) = 0$.  Show that for every $\epsilon$, we can find a $\delta > 0$ so that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{1 - \delta}^1 (n+1)x^n g(x)\,dx \leq \epsilon
$$
Use the continuity of $g$.